# Sharepoint scheduling with SSRS issue

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, moss

I have some scheduled SSRS reports (integrated mode) that get emailed by subscription. 
All of a sudden the reports have stopped being emailed. I get the error:

```
Failure sending mail: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error.
```

I don't even know where to start to look as I can't get into SSRS and my Sharepoint knowledge is lacking.

Can you help?

Comment: issue was solved by updates. Never got to bottom of problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable trace logging in SharePoint? You can activate it by going to the Central Administration website > Operations > Diagnostic Logging > Trace Logging. Perhaps we can get a more detailed error from there...